# How to remove not null constraints for multiple columns at a time in snowflake DB

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am not able to drop/ remove not null constraint in snowflake DB

Following things I have tried already...

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
alter
colname datatype DROP NOT NULL,
```

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
alter
colname datatype DROP CONSTRAINT NOT NULL,
```

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
modify column
colname datatype DROP CONSTRAINT NOT NULL,
```

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
modify column
colname datatype DROP NOT NULL,
```

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
DROP CONSTRAINT NOT NULL colname
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing `NOT NULL` property from **multiple** columns at once:

For:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(col1 INT NOT NULL,
                            col2 INT NOT NULL,
                            col3 INT NOT NULL);
```

Alter statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tab
ALTER COLUMN col1 DROP NOT NULL
     ,COLUMN col2 DROP NOT NULL
     ,COLUMN col3 DROP NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Datatype is not needed for alter column.

```
alter table tablename modify column colname DROP NOT NULL;
```

[Doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation, there is an example of what you want to do

```
alter table t1 alter column c1 drop not null;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html#examples

Comment: Please mark the question answered if you are satisfied with the answers.